# Multiple forms on one page - gather values

Tags: 7, forms

I am using the `hook_form` to create 2 different forms in a module file. Now it depends on what the URL parameters are, it can either display, one or the other or both.

Is there a function that picks up all `form_states` so i can gather values?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest form elements, so there is effectively only one form. That case you'll only need one validation and submit handler. In the end all results will be in `$form_state['values']`.

```
function form_a($form, &$form_states) {
  ..
  return $form;
}

function form_b($form, &$form_states) {
  ..
  return $form;
}

function my_form($form, &$form_states) {
  if ($need_a) {
    $form += form_a($form, &$form_states);
  }
  if ($need_b) {
    $form += form_a($form, &$form_states);
  }

  // Add the buttons.
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
    '#weight' => 5,
  );

  return $form;
}

function my_form_submit($form, &$form_states) {
  drupal_set_message(print_r($form_state['values'], TRUE));
}
```